# Multiple small sized rows vs one bigger row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I searched for an answer but I cannot find one. I have a database with posts. It is something like:

```
id | date | title | content | category_id | ....
---|------|-------|---------|-------------| ....
```

This database is used by a news service, so there are lots of posts per day. Now they told me they want to publish more posts, only with title (and maybe one-two rows of info), something like short news.

**My question is what is the optimal way to do this, as to not affect database's performance (when selecting latest rows, searching etc)?**

- To add **one single row** with the news titles as content?
- Or to add **multiple rows** with titles?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Before you think about performance, did you measure that it is actually necessary to consider performance aspects?

Comment: Why would you not add one row for each post?  I don't really understand what you are asking.  Sample data would really help.

Comment: So far, the news website published around 30 news posts per day (with title and large content). Now, they want to publish short news, too. They will post over 50 short news per day (a short information, like: "A Queens man who traded a 95-pound tortoise stolen from a nature center for $300 and a musk turtle was sentenced to six months in jail at Rikers Island."). Should this kind of short info be a row of the database, or should they publish one single row with multiple short infos (something like: "Short news for today: news A, news B, news C"), to not affect db's performance?

Comment: @C-Otto I think about performance, because the table has already over 60 000 rows, and from now it will increase with over 80 rows per day (over 29 200 rows per year).

Comment: @MMPP Is that a yes or a no? I asked a clear question.

Comment: @C-Otto It's a yes.

Comment: Is the question asking for "permission" to use normalized data to improve performance? If so...yes.

Comment: 60K rows is "small".  60M gets interesting.  60 billion is challenging.  OTOH, you can write bad SQL that will be slow.  If you want to get into more details, we can discuss that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem with the "news A, news B, news C" field list approach - how far do you go?  News F?  News X? etc.

I assume that the "info" (as you call it) is stored in a variable-length field.  If that's the case, then I'd recommend storing the short stories in the same table.  AT the size you describe the performance should be just fine.